# Golang: how to parse json that get trait and data both?

Tags: json, go

I got a dic data with {{"word name":"word meaning"},{"word name":"word meaning"},…}
I want to parse to map of the words. 
I tried to write code with interface{} but i cant imagine how to. Thanks for reading.

Comment: I know this is not valid json but data was provided like that. Is there any solution to deal with that data? Or Is there any method to change to regular json form?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a way of changing first and last curly brace, to a square brackets, then you could do the following:

package main

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {

    var raw_list []map[string]string

    var jsonText = []byte(`[
        {"Cat": "small animal"},
        {"Cow": "Big animal"}
        ]`)

    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonText, &raw_list)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("raw_list : %s\n", raw_list)

    new_map := make(map[string]string)

    for _, ele := range raw_list {
        for key, val := range ele {
            new_map[key] = val
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("new_map %s\n", new_map)
}
```

[GoPlayground](https://play.golang.org/p/Z2H8YNBrBc)

Result:

```
raw_list : [map[Cat:small animal] map[Cow:Big animal]]
new_map map[Cat:small animal Cow:Big animal]
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var jsonText = []byte(`[
    {"Name": "Cat", "Meaning": "A Cat"},
    {"Name": "Dog", "Meaning": "A Dog"}
]`)

type Word struct {
    Name, Meaning string
}

func main() {
    var words []Word
    dict := make(map[string]string)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonText, &words); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    for _, w := range words {
        dict[w.Name] = w.Meaning
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v", dict)
}
```

Produces:

> map[Cat:A Cat Dog:A Dog]

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/LVYp9E8nm_)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON should be like the following

```
{
    "word 1": "meaning 1",
    "word 2": "meaning 2"
}
```

to accomplish that you may use something like that

```
func fixJson(s string) string {
    s = strings.Replace(s, "{", "", -1)
    s = strings.Replace(s, "}", "", -1)
    return "{" + s + "}"
}
```

Full code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func fixJson(s string) string {
    s = strings.Replace(s, "{", "", -1)
    s = strings.Replace(s, "}", "", -1)
    return "{" + s + "}"
}

func main() {

    var words map[string]string

    var text = `{
        {"word 1": "meaning 1"},
        {"word 2": "meaning 2"}
    }`

    var jsonText = []byte(fixJson(text))

    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonText, &words)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(words)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/41VkZMlMrB)

Comment: This is not a good solution for technical reasons.  Specifically, it treats the content as if it were a flat string, and completely ignores structure. Consider what happens when your meanings has embedded curly braces.  The example `{{"curly": "looks like this: '{'."}}` will completely break with the proposed solution.

Comment: @dyoo fixJson function here is just an example. Probably I should mention that it will break a string in case it contain curly brace, but the main idea of solution was to lead a text to a format which can be unmarshaled into to map[string]string without extra efforts.